# Blurred canvas texture in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use blurred texture in Three.js scene, but it looks incorrect.

Canvas:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context1 = c.getContext("2d");

context1.filter = "blur(16px)";
context1.beginPath();
context1.fillStyle = "red";
context1.moveTo(35, 65);
context1.lineTo(905, 55);
context1.lineTo(605, 155);
context1.lineTo(65, 105);
context1.fill();
```

Canvas texture: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lzag9kc/

Three.js material:

```
var texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1) 
texture1.needsUpdate = true;

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
     map: texture1,
     transparent: true, 
     side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
     alphaTest: 0.5
});
```

Three.js scene: http://jsfiddle.net/h31wv2xb/5/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing "alphaTest" from your texture constructor.

Comment: You may be conflating alphaTest with alpha blending. alphaTest is a feature of alpha blending, not a flag indicating whether alpha blending is enabled or not.

AlphaTest acts like a cutoff where any alpha value falling below the alphaTest value, gets treated as zero. It's used to get hard edges on what would otherwise be a smooth transition from 1 to 0, on alpha blended images.